Use match with subset of enum for exhaustive matching
Given the following definition:
class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4

I am looking for an expression which replaces SomeExpression which will both statically assert that the value myEnum is either MyEnum.c | MyEnum.d in that branch – such that the 'never' case at the bottom correctly infers type never – and will, of course, ensure at runtime that the correct branch is taken such that 'matched' is output to the console.
def check(myEnum: MyEnum):
    match myEnum:
        case SomeExpression:
            print("matched")
        case MyEnum.a:
            pass
        case MyEnum.b:
            pass
        case never:
            assert_never(never)

I am aware that MyEnum.c | MyEnum.d is an expression satisfying this requirement but what I'm looking for is an alias for this union type that can also do the runtime check. The motivation is to be able to update this in one place so I don't have to update every match where this union is used. Obviously, I could use a predicate for this and return a set of matching values I update in one place, but this does not type-check.
Is there any such way to achieve this in python? I've tried using simpler methods like a predicate inside the match which does not narrow the type statically as desired. I've also investigated __class_getitem__ but not been able to get it working as expected.

How about case MyEnum.c | MyEnum.d?

This question is similar to: How can I combine multiple case values in a match statement?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I thought it was clear that I wasn't looking for MyEnum.c | MyEnum.d but rather some sort of alias that is both a type – and, therefore, can be used for static-checks – and a runtime entity that will select the correct branch.
The motivation here is when you have many more cases and you don't want to use the union since you'll need to update it everywhere it's used.

"I thought it was clear that I wasn't looking for MyEnum.c | MyEnum.d but rather some sort of alias that is both a type [...]": If I'm not mistaken, you want a SomeExpression = ... that can be used in both v: SomeExpression and match myEnum: case SomeExpression: .... Is that correct?

It is. Do you know of such an expression?
